# Using SHGetImageList in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, interface

I want to write a user defined type to acquire icons and such from multiple system sources in PowerShell.

With the help of this article I was trying to implement SHGetImageList to acquire large images as well: https://tabbles.net/how-to-have-large-file-icons-with-shgetfileinfo-in-c/

My code so far:

```
if ($null -eq $IconExtractor)
{
    $Signature =
    '
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr himl;
        public int i;
        public IntPtr hdcDst;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public int xBitmap;    // x offest from the upperleft of bitmap
        public int yBitmap;    // y offset from the upperleft of bitmap
        public int rgbBk;
        public int rgbFg;
        public int fStyle;
        public int dwRop;
        public int fState;
        public int Frame;
        public int crEffect;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hbmImage;
        public IntPtr hbmMask;
        public int Unused1;
        public int Unused2;
        public RECT rcImage;
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IImageList
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Add(
        IntPtr hbmImage,
        IntPtr hbmMask,
        ref int pi);

        [PreserveSig]
        int ReplaceIcon(
        int i,
        IntPtr hicon,
        ref int pi);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetOverlayImage(
        int iImage,
        int iOverlay);

        [PreserveSig]
        int Replace(
        int i,
        IntPtr hbmImage,
        IntPtr hbmMask);

        [PreserveSig]
        int AddMasked(
        IntPtr hbmImage,
        int crMask,
        ref int pi);

        [PreserveSig]
        int Draw(
        ref IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS pimldp);

        [PreserveSig]
            int Remove(
        int i);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetIcon(
        int i,
        int flags,
        ref IntPtr picon);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetImageInfo(
        int i,
        ref IMAGEINFO pImageInfo);

        [PreserveSig]
        int Copy(
        int iDst,
        IImageList punkSrc,
        int iSrc,
        int uFlags);

        [PreserveSig]
        int Merge(
        int i1,
        IImageList punk2,
        int i2,
        int dx,
        int dy,
        ref Guid riid,
        ref IntPtr ppv);

        [PreserveSig]
        int Clone(
        ref Guid riid,
        ref IntPtr ppv);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetImageRect(
        int i,
        ref RECT prc);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetIconSize(
        ref int cx,
        ref int cy);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetIconSize(
        int cx,
        int cy);

        [PreserveSig]
            int GetImageCount(
        ref int pi);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetImageCount(
        int uNewCount);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetBkColor(
        int clrBk,
        ref int pclr);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetBkColor(
        ref int pclr);

        [PreserveSig]
        int BeginDrag(
        int iTrack,
        int dxHotspot,
        int dyHotspot);

        [PreserveSig]
        int EndDrag();

        [PreserveSig]
        int DragEnter(
        IntPtr hwndLock,
        int x,
        int y);

        [PreserveSig]
        int DragLeave(
        IntPtr hwndLock);

        [PreserveSig]
        int DragMove(
        int x,
        int y);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetDragCursorImage(
        ref IImageList punk,
        int iDrag,
        int dxHotspot,
        int dyHotspot);

        [PreserveSig]
        int DragShowNolock(
        int fShow);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDragImage(
        ref POINT ppt,
        ref POINT pptHotspot,
        ref Guid riid,
        ref IntPtr ppv);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetItemFlags(
        int i,
        ref int dwFlags);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetOverlayImage(
        int iOverlay,
        ref int piIndex);
    }
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbFileInfo, uint uFlags);
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]public static extern int ExtractIconEx(string sFile, int iIndex, out IntPtr piLargeVersion, out IntPtr piSmallVersion, int amountIcons);
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#727")]public extern static int SHGetImageList(int iImageList, ref Guid riid, ref IImageList ppv);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
    
    
    public static Win32.Methods.IImageList SystemImageList(int size, ref Guid riid)
    {
        Win32.Methods.IImageList ImageList;
        SHGetImageList(size, ref riid, ref ImageList);
        return ImageList;
    }'
    $IconExtractor = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name "Methods" -Namespace Win32 -PassThru
}

$SHGFI_ICON = 0x100
$SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1;
$SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;
$SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010
$SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x4000
$SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000
$SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004

$SHIL_JUMBO = 0x4;
$SHIL_EXTRALARGE = 0x2
$iidImageList = [Guid]::new("46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950")

$ImgList = [Win32.Methods]::SystemImageList($SHIL_EXTRALARGE, [ref] $iidImageList)
```

I now have the problem that I can't create an `IImageList` object in PowerShell since it's only an interface. So I have nothing to hand over to `public extern static int SHGetImageList(int iImageList, ref Guid riid, ref IImageList ppv);`

As a workaround I tried to write a static function into my type-definition to do the work of creating the missing IImageList (see `public static Win32.Methods.IImageList SystemImageList(int size, ref Guid riid)` in my code above).

Yet my code won't run because it tells me I'm using an unasigned variable 'ImageList':

```
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\fsoh3n0a.0.cs(232) :         Win32.Methods.IImageList ImageList;
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\fsoh3n0a.0.cs(233) : >>>         SHGetImageList(size, ref riid, ref ImageList);
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\fsoh3n0a.0.cs(234) :         return ImageList;
```

Attempt number 2 by using `out ImageList` instead of `ref ImageList`: It tells me I'm using unsuitable arguments for this method.

```
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\f3lmsw2k.0.cs(232) :         Win32.Methods.IImageList ImageList;
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\f3lmsw2k.0.cs(233) : >>>         SHGetImageList(size, ref riid, out ImageList);
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\f3lmsw2k.0.cs(234) :         return ImageList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy of the code doesn't match method signatures.

This line:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#727")]public extern static int SHGetImageList(int iImageList, ref Guid riid, ref IImageList ppv);
```

Should be:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#727")]private extern static int SHGetImageList(int iImageList, ref Guid riid, out IImageList ppv);
```

Then your call should be:

```
SHGetImageList(size, ref riid, out ImageList);
```

For `ImageList` parameter, change `ref` to `out`.

This will at the very least compile without errors. I haven't tested rest of the functionality after it compiles.